# Growth order of numbers whose prime factors are all congruent to +1 or -1 modulo 8

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Here are the numbers whose prime factors all congruent to $\pm 1\pmod 8$:
http://oeis.org/A058529

My questions are:

(1) What is the order of growth of these numbers? That is, what is the order of magnitude of the $n$th smallest among them?

(2) For the numbers whose prime factors are all congruent to $\pm 3\pmod 8$, is the order of growth the same as in (1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an old question (and according to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265160/density-of-numbers-whose-prime-factors-belong-to-given-arithmetic-progressions), the result you seek was proven by Landau). In particular, it follows from this that if $S$ is a set of arithmetic progressions containing a density $1/2$ set of the primes, then number of $n \leq x$ all of whose prime factors in $S$ is asymptotic to some constant times $C \frac{x}{\sqrt{\log(x)}}$. This implies that the $n$th positive integer $q_{n}$ all of whose prime factors are $\pm 1 \pmod{8}$ satisfies $q_{n} \sim C_{1} n \sqrt{\log(n)}$. Similarly, if $r_{n}$ is the $n$th positive integer all of whose prime factors are $\pm 3 \pmod{8}$, then $r_{n} \sim C_{2} n \sqrt{\log(n)}$.

If you are looking for a modern treatment of this, which will enable you to compute the constants $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, this result is stated in [Cojocaru and Murty's book "An introduction to sieve methods and their applications"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-sieve-methods-and-their-applications/A7B896FAE6B543D73F4FDBDA8609BAC6), but I don't have my copy at home right now, so I can't tell you exactly where in the book to look.

Comment: Shouldn't this be $q_n \sim C_1  n \sqrt{\log(n)}$ (and similarly for $r_n$)?

Comment: Indeed it should be. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Can it be generalized to sets of arithmetic progressions containing a density  $ \delta >0$ of the primes ?

Comment: Yes, and in that case the number of such integers $\leq x$ is $\sim C \frac{x}{\log(x)^{1-\delta}}$.

Comment: Thank you. That's precisely what I expected but I feared it might be too naive.

Comment: By the way, does the involved constant  $ C $ depend exclusively on  $ \delta $? If so do we know an expression thereof ?

Comment: Can you please tell me where it is in the book? I'm not an expert on number theory and cannot find it. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the Tauberian theorem on page 25. You should apply this with $a_n = 1$ if all the prime factors of $n$ are $\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$. The resulting Dirichlet series is $F(s) = \sqrt{\zeta(s) L(s,\chi_{8})}$, where $\chi_{8}$ is the unique primitive quadratic Dirichlet character of conductor $8$. I hope this helps.