# Density of numbers with a prime factor satisfying a congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of integers with at least one prime factor in the arithmetic progression $km+d$, $(m, d)=1$. I am looking for results on the density of $S$. I found [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265160/density-of-numbers-whose-prime-factors-belong-to-given-arithmetic-progressions?newreg=50d48ea8ab304e91b4d0271dd084b376) which talked about the density of the set of integers whose prime factors are all in the arithmetic progression, though I cannot find the citation from Landau.

If anyone can point me to results of this type that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the density is $1$. Out near infinity, numbers have lots of prime factors, it's hard for all of them to avoid one given congruence class.

Answer (score 10):

Let $P$ be any non-empty finite set of primes. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the density of integers not having a prime factor in $P$ is
$\prod_{p\in P}(1-1/p)$, which is smaller than $\exp(-\sum_{p\in P}1/p)$. It is known that the sum of reciprocals of primes in the OP's arithmetic progression $A$ diverges (see Serre: A course in arithmetic), hence for any $\epsilon>0$ one can choose $P\subset A$ such that the above density is less than $\epsilon$. It follows that the density of $S$ exceeds $1-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, hence it equals one.

Comment: Does this imply that for any prime $p$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $p|r_{0}(n)$ where $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ assuming $p$ belongs to some given such arithmetic progression?